# overriding default RegistrationPolicy on AnnotationMBeanExporter in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jmx

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jmx/JmxAutoConfiguration.java

shows

```
RegistrationPolicy.FAIL_ON_EXISTING
```

being set.

We are using spring boot created WARs in a standalone tcserver. 
New deployments occur before old versions are un-deployed so you can have multiple versions deployed.

I am already using

```
spring.jmx.default-domain=[app name]
```

to avoid clashes across apps...but

We are seeing errors like

```
UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean with  key 'dataSourceMBean'
  nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException
```

for our datasource Mbean across different version of the same app.

I would like to set a

```
RegistrationPolicy.IGNORE_EXISTING
```

as per http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jmx.html#jmx-exporting-registration-behavior.

Can I do this easily while maintaining the ObjectNamingStrategy and defaultDomain? Although not at all difficult, I am hoping I don't have to pretty much override all of JmxAutoConfiguration?

shame there is not a

```
spring.jmx.mbeanExporter.registrationPolicy
```

spring boot property

Cheers

Answer (score 7):

Although this question was asked some time ago and maybe you have already found the answer, I will give my 2 cents here once I faced this problem and found a solution that worked for me.

Initially it was not completely clear what I needed to do, but when carefully reading the same spring documentation you provided in your question I figured out you can control the registration behavior on SpringBoot by introducing the class annotation

`@EnableMBeanExport(registration=RegistrationPolicy.IGNORE_EXISTING)`

to allow Spring ignore a second JMX registration if the MBean was already registered, as can be seen [at the spring documentation here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jmx.html#jmx-context-mbeanexport)